# Error establishing a database connection on Amazon ec2

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I've researched this topic and all the other posts thoroughly for the past few months and not permanent solution works.

I installed Wordpress on an Amazon EC2 server using Putty SSH. My website works wonderfully until I run Facebook and Instagram ads that drive massive traffic to the website (www.ProfRoofs.com). After a few minutes of the ad running, the home page displays..

> "Error establishing a database connection"

I tried solutions on here including editing the wp-config.php file to include those suggested FTP credentials. I read about creating a load balancer but find that inefficient. The only temporary solution that works is rebooting my instance, but that gets annoying to do all the time.

Should I pay for the $50/month support from Amazon to fix it? I am wondering if it is because I am using the free tier EC2 instance and it is too small/not enough memory? I read a post about increasing the memory and I did that to 3GB and that still did nothing.

Any suggestions? Struggling to get a business running here.

Comment: If this is a high traffic site instead of using local MYSQL use MYSQL RDS

Comment: you can track how much traffic you are getting and how much connection you are serving at the error time, note down it.

See if you can switch to RDS+ EC2 as jbird suggested.

Also you can use varnish HTTP accelerator to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your EC2 instance does not have sufficient memory to handle the increased workload. I have seen this a lot with t2.micro instances running Wordpress and a local MySQL database. Performance will be fine until load increases and then database connection errors will start.

You can do one of two things:

1. You can use a larger EC2 instance. Through the AWS console, just stop your instance, change its instance type, and start it. I would increase the instance type gradually to avoid paying for more than what you need.
2. You can offload your MySQL database to an RDS instance and remove MySQL from the EC2 instance. This will definitely be beneficial but it is still possible you will require a larger instance type during times of peak traffic. RDS is available through the AWS free-tier.